# What to tell when an employer asks about my co-worker's weaknesses?

Tags: hiring-process, references

So me and my coworker are programmers. My coworker is applying to different jobs. He asked me if I can be a reference and I said yes. In mine opinion, my coworker is one of the best programmers I ever met and has earn my respect. He does his job well and is a good mentor and a good friend.

I am afraid of being asked about weaknesses from employers and recruiters. I feel that as a reference, I should put my coworker in a good light and not tarnish his reputation.

The best thing I can come up with is:

> Out of my two and half years working with person X, his weaknesses
>   were not made apparent to me. I have the utmost respect for person X.

So how should I answer this question if the question is asked?

Comment: Exactly like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you pretty much answered your question with your template. It may not be a terrible idea to tone it down a little bit, to avoid the possibility that you were "coached" into writing that answer. However, if you have a solid LinkedIn presence, or a respected senior position, they will likely not question your referral.

To make some slight corrections for readability...

> Over the two and half years I worked alongside JimBob, I did not observe any weaknesses. He is a strong programmer, and a strong mentor. I have the utmost respect for JimBob. He would be an incredible asset for your company.